# Context-free grammar for language L = a^(2^k)

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory

As part of a Computation Theory exercise, I am asked to find a context free language for the language L = a^(2^k).

How I tried tackling it: I want to work with an **X** sentence that recursively doubles all the a's that were produced by other sentences. That will lead me only to strings like a, a^2, a^4, a^8 which is the grammar I'm looking for.

But is such a thing possible? How can I do this?

```
S -> aS | X | ε
Χ -> (doubles all previous a's)
```

And there is also the problem of doubling a string of `a`s that would yield a number of `a`s not accepted by the a^(2^k) condition, for example a^3, a^5, a^6 all fall "in-between" the progression gaps of a^(2^k).

Comment: This might be rather suited for the [CS SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages.  Consider k such that 2^k > p...

Comment: No dice, how can I incorporate it through P?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the string `a^(2^p)` in your language, where `p` is the constant in the pumping lemma for context-free languages. We can write this string as `uvxyz` such that:

- `|vy| >= 1`
- `|vxy| <= p`

Then we know that if the language is context free, then all strings of the form `u v^n x y^n z` should be in the language for `n >= 0`. Let's call `a = |uxz|` and `b = |vy|`. Then we must have strings in the language of length `a, a + b, a + 2b, ...`. Suppose `a = 2^k` is a power of 2 and that `a + b` is also a power of 2. Then `b = 2^m - 2^k` and `a + 2b = 2^(m+1) - 2^k = 2^j` is also a power of 2. Rewrite this as `2^(m+1) = 2^k + 2^j`. Divide through by the smaller of `k` and `j` to get `2^r = 2^s + 1`. The only way this equation can be satisfied is if `s = 0`, that is, if `k = j`, since otherwise the RHS is odd while the LHS must be even. But then `m = k` also and `b = 0`. But `b` must be greater than 0, by the pumping lemma.

Man that was ugly but you get the idea.